# Setting int to zero in contructor

Tags: java

I have some problem with constructors. I'm leraning java and I'm trying to make a programm that recognize your input. I don't know how to set int to null like I set String to null and Date to null;

```
public Osebo(String Name,String Surname){
    this(Name,Surname,(String)null,_________,(Date)null)
}
public Osebo(String Name,String Surname,int old){
    this(Name,priimek,(String)null,starost,(Date)null);
}
public Osebo(String ime,String priimek,String naslov,int starost){
    this(ime,priimek,naslov,starost,(Date)null);
}

public Osebo(String ime, String priimek, String naslov, int starost, Calendar datum) {
    this(ime,priimek,naslov,starost,datum.getTime());
}

public Osebo(String ime, String priimek, String naslov, int starost, Date datum) {
    this.ime = ime;
    this.priimek = priimek;
    this.naslov = naslov; 
    this.starost = starost;
    this.datum = datum;
}
```

Comment: You can't set `int` to `null`. Set it to zero

Comment: `int` is set to 0 by default, so you don't even need to set it explicitly

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a primitive. It can never be null. You can use `Integer` instead, which can be assigned null.

If you still want to use `int`, choose a default value to represent the absence of a value (for example, -1 can work for you if the valid values of that variable are non-negative).

Answer (score 1):

Primitives can't be assigned null.
You can either set default value (say -1) or wrap it in Integer.

Answer (score 0):

In java primitives can not be set to null instead use wrapper class if you want to set type variable to null. And one more thing that you don't need to cast null to any object you can assign null directly to object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the java you can not set `int` to `null` because as if an primitive there as to be single value that is `0`. that is by default.  but you can not set it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know null basically means "not pointing to any object". Therefore only reference variables can be set to null because reference variables points to objects. Int is a primitive data type, not an object. You might set it to 0 as a default value. But if you really want an object rapper of int, use Integer instead.